# Contract for an interview

Tags: interviewing, united-states

We are a photography company in process of hiring for sales representative position. Basically this person would visit businesses (restaurants, hotels, retails, gyms…) to offer one of our services.
However, we thought it would be great to have some kind of contract that applicants would sign before we conduct an actual interview.
By signing this contract potential applicant should give us permission to record the entire interview, check the information that give us about themselves (sort of running a background check). From our point, we promise that the information would stay confidential.
Also, we are located in Maryland and if we hire people from different states what are some of the challenges I should be prepared to address? 
Another thing, we tend to have three types of interviews:

1. Over the phone
2. Via video call
3. Face-to-face

Would it be typical to have three different contracts? Or is having a single contract more standard?

Just trying to get an idea if we actually need this type of contracts and what are the things that we should include.

In the future we are going to hire them as contractors.

Comment: This all seems to be stuff companies do without needing a "contract" approving it. Have you asked a lawyer whether this is at all necessary?

Comment: _By signing this contract potential applicant should give us permission to ... check the information that give us about themselves_. When you fill out the application it seems to me that you are already giving permission to have your information checked. For audio/video recordings, you probably should get proper legal advice to see what should be done for getting the permission if required.

Comment: Personally, this would sound very fishy to me--I'm asked to sign a contract prior to an interview, and submit to everything being recorded? And then two more contracts before I maybe get the job?

Comment: This seems like a legal question.

Comment: Hmmm this seems a bit strange. The only contracts I ever heard of in the context of interviewing are NDAs...

Comment: The question: "Also, we are located in Maryland and if we hire people from different states what are some of the challenges I should be prepared to address" is a completely different question, Because it involves tax law.

Comment: If I came to an interview, and you showed me that contract, I'd just tear it up.

Comment: If you were to present such a contract to me at the time of interview, I would either walk out the door or at least sit down and read every word of the contract before even thinking about signing it. If you really must do the contract thing, send it to the employee with the interview invitation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. You don't want a video recording of your first interviews. As beginner interviewers, you're very likely to make mistakes interviewing people and possibly ask [illegal questions](https://www.dllr.state.md.us/oeope/preemp.shtml).

Or worse yet, you don't ask any illegal question, but someone suspects you of picking someone less qualified than them because of their race, or their gender, or their age, and now all those videos are discoverable should they file a lawsuit.

Also, don't call the job application form a contract, that's going to scare away people. In a way, it is a contract because usually there is verbiage that you give permission to check the information you give (but no one calls it a contract!). It's a job application. Period.

And if you do hire a third party to do the background check, they're going to expect that application form (perhaps with a couple of manual annotations added by the interviewer), but not some videotape they'll have to transcribe.

Furthermore, if you really wanted to videotape them during their interview, I think you should compensate them for their time. I realize that actors get videotaped all the time during auditions, but this is just a sales job, a contract sales job at that, and probably not a high paying one (I assume). I feel your company is already investing very little in the relationship. In this case, asking to videotape them without special compensation only makes the process seem even more unfair and unconventional to the person being interviewed.

Comment: Worse yet, if you destroy the videos, then any court will assume that you destroyed them because they contained evidence against you. So you better keep all the videos for the next six years or so.

Comment: @gnasher729 Not necessarily.  Provided you have a company policy that specifies when old recordings will be destroyed, then there is nothing suspicious about deleting them in line with that policy.  You just have to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

In general these types of contracts are not used. If the position requires an extensive background check the company you hire for that service will be able to provide the required verbiage for any paperwork the applicant must sign.

It is also unusual to record interviews for most positions. An exception would be a position where they are being evaluated on how they move and talk. Athletes, actors, news readers, and performers expect that they will be recorded. Others would view your desire to record the interview with skepticism.

If you do insist on have formal pre-interview contracts you will have to get a lawyer involved to draft the contracts, otherwise they may not protect you from the things you are concerned about.